# headless browser is still visible

Tags: python, python-3.x

im very new in programming and i tried already to open chrome headless but i always got different errors and no solution. Now i use firefox and get no errors but the opened browser is still visible.

i use windows 10, python 3.7.

```
import webbrowser, time, random, threading

from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
def main():
    hreading.Timer(25., main).start()
    wortEingabe = (first, second, third)  # zufällige Eingabe
    wort = random.choice(wortEingabe)
    options = FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = 
    webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\webdriver\geckodriver.exe")
    search_url = "https://www.amazon.de/s?k=+" + str(wort) + 
    "&__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&ref=nb_sb_noss_1"
    driver.get(search_url)
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.quit()

main()
```

thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
options.add_argument("--headless")
```

use

```
options.headless = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just found, via https://intoli.com/blog/running-selenium-with-headless-firefox/ a few comments on this. That blog, refering to using `options.add_argument("--headless")` or `options.headless = True`:

> However, on current versions of Firefox (up to and including Nightly 58.0a1) running on Windows 10 this flag doesn’t seem to work. Luckily, we can achieve the same effect by setting the `MOZ_HEADLESS` environment variable either from the command line with set `MOZ_HEADLESS=1` or from the python script itself as above.

Even though that blogs not new, I still seemed to have this problem too. So, adding the following was the only thing that allowed this to work on my computer:

```
import os

os.environ['MOZ_HEADLESS'] = '1'
```